# Reacting to VoiceOver events

Tags: cocoa-touch, accessibility

In my app, I have a view that cycles through a number of images. Non-VoiceOver users are able to swipe over the view in order to move backward or forward in the list of images. I've used the UIAccessibilityContainer protocol to properly fill this with accessibility elements so that VoiceOver users are able to "hear" all the items in this set by going through them with the one-finger next/previous item gestures.

What I can't figure out is how to update the image in the UI based on these events. Now, I realize VoiceOver is geared towards blind users and it's probably not a *huge* deal if the UI doesn't update, but some VoiceOver users are only partly blind, and it's a point of performing the correct behavior regardless.

Is there a way to tell when the user has selected a different element in an accessibility container so that I can update the UI accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could the UIAccessibilityFocus Protocol be what you're looking for? Specifically `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused`? I would guess each element in your container should get this called when VoiceOver moves focus to them.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like what I want. I'll have to rearchitect things a bit to try it out (I was just creating UIAccessibilityElements by hand like the docs suggest, so there's nothing to "get" that message).

Comment: I've tried to override the functions from the `UIAccessibilityFocus` protocol, but nothing gets fired when in VoiceOver and the elements are focused. Any ideas? I've added a custom UITableViewCell, and a custom UITextField...